# NUNJUCKS setting a variable

Tags: nunjucks

Hi all Im calling data from a json file. Whe I create the following loop:

```
{% for item in resume.applications %}
    <span class="expanded uppercase">{{ item.fields.Job }}</span>
    {{ item.fields.intro | safe }}
    {% endfor %}
```

The span renders with the correct html content. However if I try to set a variable without a loop:

```
{% set job = resume.applications %}
<span>{{ job.fields.intro }}</span>
```

I get nothing? Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

I get nothing

Comment: After `{% set job = resume.applications %}` you have `job` as array. Array doesn't have `.fields` property and hence `job.fields` is null and you have an empty output.

Comment: Thank you for your time Aikon, so to set the value of job would it be {% set job = resume.applications.fileds.intro %} ? I have tryed this but no luck

Comment: Nope. The first variant is OK. What do you want by second? I suppose that `resume.applications` is an array and it doesn't have `fields` prop (but members of array have it).

Comment: the logs return: 
[
Record { //<- no colon after Record?
 fields: {
   intro: "string"
 }
}
]

Comment: Try `resume.applications[0].fields.intro`.

Comment: Got it sorted here, but thank you for your patience https://stackoverflow.com/q/64380209/482095